# Should I add a div class to a fields TPL file or just change my CSS file?

Tags: views, theming

I am starting to understand how to edit the CSS of individual views on my site. I use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module (release 2). I know Views 3 makes life easier in these things but for now I have to use Views 2.

I have a comment block on my site. I wondering if it is best/easier to add some kind of div class to a fields TPL file or wether I could just change it in my CSS file. I seem to have tried both in my time with various success. I really struggle to find out what part of the div class I need to change in a view when viewing it with Firebug.

This for instance:

> view view-comments-recent view-id-comments_recent view-display-id-block view-dom-id-5

Would I make the css something like

> .view-comments-recent view-id-comments_recent view-display-id-block view-dom-id-5 body {
>         font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>         font-size:12px;
>         line-height:16px;
>       }

to change the text in the comment field?

I feel it might be better to create a `views-view-field--comments-recent--block--comment.tpl.php` file and then do something like this:

```
 <div class="mynewclass"><the print output bit> </div>
```

And then add this:

```
.mynewclass body {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:16px;
}
```

Or maye that would be like so:

```
.mynewclass p {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:16px;
}
```

Could anyone help me with what I am trying to do? I feel like I almost have it.

Which way would be best do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set a custom css class for each field, but otherwise your technique of drilling down using css classes is fairly common practice.

Comment: Thanks boombatower. Truth be told i was just in a bit of a panic when i posted. things are starting to make more sense to me. I think i just need to learn more about css.